# How to set up a vhost to autoindex the files using nginx

Tags: linux, web-services, http, nginx

I just add a vhost in nginx.conf for autoindexing files like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name res.rickyzhang.me;
    root  /home/wwwroot/default/res;
    location = / {
        autoindex      on;
    }
    access_log  /home/wwwlogs/access_res.log  access;
}
```

i think this would work,but when i visit res.rickyzhang.me,it always give me a 400 response code,it means the request is invalid and can not be understood by the server,i am confused.Can anybody help me?Thanks.

Comment: why don't you add an error_log and look there for clues?

Comment: @Michael Tabolsky,actually the vhost doesn't receive the request,the response code 400 demonstrate that the request is invalid,so there is no error log to have a look,just have a access log record in the access.log

Comment: hmhm, if you get something in the /home/wwwlogs/access_res.log then apparently you do get the request inside "vhost", right? so error_log should have a relative indication. If, instead, you get it in another file, then your question seems irrelevant since you don't get the request to the correct server section.

Comment: @Michael Tabolsky i also think the nginx process doesn't get the request to the correct vhost,maybe i should try to find out the reason,it really confuse me,but thanks for your idea

Comment: @ricky_hust I think you should use a separate access log for this vhost so you can understand which vhost is matching.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try adding a `try_files` in it

```
location = / {
    autoindex      on;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}
```

Comment: it is useless,the same wrong result,but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just tried on one of my servers:

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)

server {
    server_name  some_hostname;

    location = / {
        root   html;
        autoindex on;
#http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAutoindexModule
#The request only reaches the ngx_http_autoindex_module when 
#the ngx_http_index_module did not find an index file.
        index  should_not_exist;
    }
}
```

works as expected

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether it is appropriate to answer myself.

yesterday,i checked my nginx.conf carefully,i really counldn't find anything wrong.the 400 response code gives me some clues,so i just changed the hostname from res to dw,others have not changed,it worked!

it really amaze me,i guess maybe res is a reserved word in nginx,but i search on google,there isn't anything related to this.